# New Rails application bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I'm getting this error when trying to create a new Rails project:

```
/Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in require: cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in rescue in require
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in require
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:319:in bundle_command
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:335:in run_bundle
from (eval):1:in run_bundle 
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in invoke_command
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in block in invoke_all
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in each
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in map
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in invoke_all
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in dispatch
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in start
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in <top (required)>
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in require
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in require
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in <top (required)>
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in require
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in require
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/bin/rails:9:in <top (required)>
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rails:23:in load
from /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I `cd`'d into my project and ran `bundle install` and I got this error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/.autotest
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.7.1 succeeds before bundling.
```

If I run `gem install nokogirl` I get the "Errno::EACCES" error again.

I'm not sure what to do to solve this. I read the Bundler and Nokogirl documentation but that hasn't helped.

Just in case, I'm running:

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

My Gem ENV is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
 - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY:    /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
 - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jameslett/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin
 - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jameslett/.gem/specs
 - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY:    /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/etc
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-14
 - GEM PATHS:
  - /Users/jameslett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - /Users/jameslett/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
  - https://rubygems.org/
```

Is my gem path causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you own all the files in the `.rbenv` folder.

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/jameslett/.rbenv
```

In addition all files should be readable and writable.

```
$ chmod -R u+rw /Users/jameslett/.rbenv
```

Permissions may be messed up when combining sudo with the actual user's environment.

Comment: Thank you! I think the files we not writable (probably why nokogirl wouldn't install) which is strange; I'm not sure if it's because I update my OS, or something entirely different. But I'll have to hunt around more and see what might have caused this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Comment: Sadly that didn't work it tells me I have the latest version installed. I still get the "Errno::EACCES" error again. Any other suggestions?